# saving user defaults [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, c4

I saw a couple of examples but I cannot figure out what's going wrong when trying to save my text field input and reload it when restarting the app.
I have something like this in my .m file (.h file only has a `<UITextViewDelegate>`);

```
@implementation C4WorkSpace{
    UITextView *textField;
    C4Button *okButton;
    C4Label *savedText;
}

-(void)setup {
    //add text field
    CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20, self.canvas.width-40, 124.0f);
    textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    textField.delegate = self;
    //textField.hidden=true;

    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    okButton=[C4Button buttonWithType:ROUNDEDRECT];
    [okButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:NORMAL];
    okButton.center=self.canvas.center;
    [self.canvas addUIElement:okButton];
    [okButton runMethod:@"saveDefault" target:self forEvent:TOUCHUPINSIDE];

    savedText=[C4Label labelWithText:@"default"];
    savedText.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.center.x, self.canvas.center.y+40);
    [self.canvas addLabel:savedText];
}
-(void)saveDefault{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:textField.text forKey:@"userName"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    C4Log(@"defaults: %@",defaults);
    C4Log(@"defaults: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"]);
    savedText.text=textField.text;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSMutableString *text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    C4Log(@"loadedText:%s", text);
    textField.text=text;
    savedText.text=text;
}
@end
```

I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong, but when I restart the app the loadedText is always: "¯8*:å". Doesn't matter what I saved.

Comment: what is problem in this

Comment: Try to use NSString instead NSMutableString in viewDidLoad

Comment: Where is runMethod ??

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is. You might find it useful to read [ask]

Comment: @Firegab tried it but still loaded view only gives me this "¯8*:å" whenever I run it...

Comment: @JamesWebster sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: try to set value instead og object.. setValue:forKey and get it with valueForKey:

Comment: @Firegab doesn't change anything either

Comment: In logs made in saveDefault the value appear correct?

Comment: @Firegab yes. the label also updates correctly.

Comment: what is this method     savedText=[C4Label labelWithText:@"default"]; "default" is this key of default you are truing to get object or ?. Save the textfield text to string and set it to defaults.

Comment: it's just creating a label that will when pressing the button update to be the same as the textfield text. I added it only to see whether the button works or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easiest solution is to set in

---

**ViewDidLoad**

```
text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

and in **setup**

```
if (text!=nil) {
        textField.text=text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does Setup method is call ? I think in viewDidLoad you initialize, but setup method called earlier.
You don't save this info,so button don't recognizer or load info and set text before initialization.
in setup method load info

```
UItextView *k = [UItextView alloc] init];
k.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

and take a look what will be.

UPDATE:

That's wrong;

```
[c4workspace loadInfoFromDefaults];
[c4workspace alloc]init];  (calls viedidload method with load info)
```

You need

```
[c4workspace alloc]init]; 
[c4workspace loadInfoFromDefaults];
```

Please post code where you create c4WorkSpace object.

UPDATE 2:

```
-(void)setup {

    //add text field
    CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20, self.canvas.width-40, 124.0f);
    textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    textField.delegate = self;
    //textField.hidden=true;

    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    okButton=[C4Button buttonWithType:ROUNDEDRECT];
    [okButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:NORMAL];
    okButton.center=self.canvas.center;
    [self.canvas addUIElement:okButton];
    [okButton runMethod:@"saveDefault" target:self forEvent:TOUCHUPINSIDE];

    savedText=[C4Label labelWithText:@"default"];
    savedText.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.center.x, self.canvas.center.y+40);
    [self.canvas addLabel:savedText];
}

- (void) setTextView
{
    textField.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    savedText.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
}
```

So you call this like:

```
C4WorkSpace *c4 = [C4WorkSpace alloc] init];
[c4 setup]
[c4 setTextView];
```

Comment: could you explain this a bit more? How would that comment help me?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called before the setup.

Comment: and that's wrong, you call viewDidLoad, and there set variable to undefined uitextview, so text will be not right. 
You need call viewdidload without loading from default

Comment: so what is the solution then? setting up the textfield in viewDidLoad?

Comment: check out my answer, i updated it twice. for example creating textfield in viewDidLoad, or set .text parameter in setup method.

Comment: thanks. through you I found what's going wrong!! I posted another answer to this. To me that's the easiest solution..

Comment: you anyway need this to make in setup method or after, and your solution is strange, because if defaults nor found, then it will return nil and nil will set to text, so text will be @"", you needn't to check if string != nil

Comment: Also in SO always if answer is helpful, then sets checkmark and up vote him.